# java.lang.RuntimeException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, centos7, google-chrome-headless

I trying to render the webpage using chromedriver on centos7.I have installed both `google-chrome` and `chromedriver` .I am starting the chromedriver using the following command.

```
$ chromedriver --port=9515 --headless --whitelisted-ips="myip" --disable-dev-shm-usage --log-path='chrome.log'
Starting ChromeDriver 74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}) on port 9515
Remote connections are allowed by a whitelist (myip).
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
```

I am running the google chrome using the following command

```
$ google-chrome --headless --remote-debugging-port=9222 --disable-gpu
xcb_connection_has_error() returned true

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9222/devtools/browser/cf6b15dd-0e37-4106-88ed-01b959252da4
```

Here we have `google-chrome` and `chromedriver` running.But when my Java application try to connect to the port at which the chromedriver is running i am getting the following error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Linux 3.10.0-862.3.2.el7.x86_64 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

I have tried out the same in my windows environment it works fine.

```
version:
ChromeDriver 74.0.3729.6
Google Chrome 74.0.3729.131
```

Comment: did you tried to launch google-chrome in background? (using &) . did you checked before running your java program that there is a google-chrome process running ? please share your Java code as well

Comment: Yes I did but it did not fix the problem

Comment: try to downgrade your chrome browser version try 70